# Popup a part of the html background on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media

I have a background image in my html page. I want it to popup when I hover over a part of it.

I did this by putting an image over the backgroung with `opacity: 0` and my function did was putting `opacity: 1` when hovering over the image.
But when the screen size changes, the image position changes.

Comment: So what's your question? Post your code as a full working example jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't be using it in background image. Can you rather use a regular img tag, and then you can define a usemap attribute to it, and map the areas using a map.

This approach is explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

You can put a javascript:functionName() for href attribute of any area in a map.

Comment: Thank you for this tip! Very helpful